# how to Set a limit to GCS bucket

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-iam

I am new to GCP, so I am trying to set a 100 GB quota per month on one single GCS bucket. so a user who has access to that bucket can upload up to 100 GB of files per month. Does anyone have any idea how to do this?

Any help will be appreciated.
Thank You

Comment: How is a user to upload their data?  Are you saying that they will have a Google Account and write permissions to the bucket?   One way might be to have a front end app receive the incoming user request and have that proxy the request to GCS which checks in a database how much they have already uploaded that month rather than letting them go straight to GCS.

Comment: Users can use the bucket for ETL purposes, to land a file in GCS, not through any app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Cloud does not have a quota setting for buckets to limit storage space.

Additionally, Google Cloud has no knowledge of your users, only Google Cloud IAM identities.

To implement a quota as you described, that quota must be implemented by your own logic inside your application and enforced by methods you create/manage/control.

The cost for storage itself is very low. The real cost is bandwidth which is more expensive than the storage costs. You will have an issue with how to measure and charge your customers for egress costs. Google does not break pricing into object based costs.